# How to deploy Azure from GitHub release not repository?

Tags: git, azure, deployment

It is possible to do deployment to Azure from GitHub release not repository?
For ex. 
http://github.com/grandnode/grandnode we want to use button Deploy to Azure, but in installation process Azure copy files from actual repository, which is uncomplete. Is there any chance to change it?

Regards,
Patryk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that deploying from a repository works, is that it copies the entire repository, gets any dependencies (via NPM etc) and that is the configured site.

[Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) the technology behind the deployments has a number of configuration options that will allow for more complex deployments.

However, it would probably be a much simplier process to fork that project, and have your own pre-configured deployment that you can point to (and have the 'deploy to azure' button, if you so require)

Comment: Thanks for help. I will try it.